# Robotic Arm - Claw Object Offset problem

Tags: objects

[image]Open claw:
[image: screenshot 1]

Closed claw:
[image: screenshot 2]

I was making robotic hands from the Polyfjord tutorial "[How to Create Robotic Arms in Blender](https://youtu.be/-2HCxy4Kh4E)", only I ran into a problem with Claws. When I do an object offset to duplicate, the copies are sometimes very high and sometimes very small. Anyone is able to help?

[image]

Comment: hello, your link asks for an authorization

Comment: Images can be placed directly in your question, no need for links. For the file please use https://blend-exchange.com or https://pasteall.org/blend/ and post the generated link in your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the problem? It's not clear when and what gets *"very high and sometimes very small. "*.

Comment: @Blunder done :)

Comment: Thanks for the image. Now, what do you mean by "very high" and "very small"? You have modeled the triangle and the upper "claw finger" and added an armature to the "finger". It also has an *Array Modifier* that creates the 2 copies of the finger at the bottom. The triangle object is the pivot point for the rotation of the "fingers". The scale and bending look fine to me. Just the 2 fingers copies are a bit out of place because the pivot point is not in the center. (The distance of the world origin and the x-axis is used by Blender.) Is this what you mean? They are out of place?

Comment: @Blunder 
now I somehow gave them the way they are but they cannot be moved to a normal place, unfortunately sometimes it happens like this ... I don't know how to say it so I added a second photo

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you tried to scale the triangle object? (the one that you named "Circle" ;-) If you want to change its size (key S) you can do this but you have to apply the scale to reset the scale (key Ctrl+A > *Scale* in *Object* mode). Check the value of *Transformation > Scale* in the side panel. It should be 1.0,1.0,1.0. That's important because it is used by the *Array Modifier*. If the scale is not 1.0 then the copies will shrink or grow one by one.

Comment: @Blunder it's 1.0 1.0 1.0 :cc

Comment: @Blunder YES I DID IT, idk how, I just noticed that the claw is directed to one point which is not visible but it highlights when I select the claw so I did it again and somehow this point is in the middle and everything works

Comment: Cheers! I'm glad you solved it! I still don't know how you messed up the sizes without changing the scale?! Is the *"one point which is not visible but highlights when I select the claw"* a little orange dot? That could be the object's origin and the cause for the offset when it's not at the same spot as the triangle's origin.